# org.springframework.jms.JmsSecurityException: Access denied to resource: type=<jms>

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I'm receiving a `JmsSecurityException` when publish to a secured WebLogic JMS queue using a Spring's `JmsTemplate`. The troubling part is that I'm able to publish successfully using an equivalent non-Spring bit of code.

Below is the exception being thrown (assuming the destination is `QUEUE.IN`).

```
org.springframework.jms.JmsSecurityException: Access denied to resource: type=<jms>, application=DistQueue-Module, destinationType=queue, resource=QUEUE.IN, action=send; nested exception is weblogic.jms.common.JMSSecurityException: Access denied to resource: type=<jms>, application=DistQueue-Module, destinationType=queue, resource=QUEUE.IN, action=send
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:291)
        at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:168)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:469)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:534)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:526)
        at com.company.jms.publisher.service.impl.JmsServiceImpl.sendMessage(JmsServiceImpl.java:34)
        at com.company.jms.publisher.service.impl.JmsServiceImpl.publish(JmsServiceImpl.java:29)
        at com.company.jms.publisher.controller.MainController.postIt(MainController.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
2013-11-07 19:26:56.506:WARN::Nested in org.springframework.jms.JmsSecurityException: Access denied to resource: type=<jms>, application=DistQueue-Module, destinationType=queue, resource=QUEUE.IN, action=send; nested exception is weblogic.jms.common.JMSSecurityException: Access denied to resource: type=<jms>, application=DistQueue-Module, destinationType=queue, resource=QUEUE.IN, action=send:
weblogic.jms.common.JMSSecurityException: Access denied to resource: type=<jms>, application=DistQueue-Module, destinationType=queue, resource=QUEUE.IN, action=send
        at weblogic.jms.common.JMSSecurityHelper.checkPermission(JMSSecurityHelper.java:162)
        at weblogic.jms.backend.BEDestinationSecurityImpl.checkSendPermission(BEDestinationSecurityImpl.java:74)
        at weblogic.jms.backend.BEDestinationImpl.checkPermission(BEDestinationImpl.java:2513)
        at weblogic.jms.backend.BEDestinationImpl.sendInitialize(BEDestinationImpl.java:1565)
        at weblogic.jms.backend.BEDestinationImpl.send(BEDestinationImpl.java:2079)
        at weblogic.jms.backend.BEDestinationImpl.wrappedSend(BEDestinationImpl.java:2051)
        at weblogic.jms.backend.BEDestinationImpl.invoke(BEDestinationImpl.java:1539)
        at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:961)
        at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.dispatchAsyncInternal(DispatcherImpl.java:140)
        at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherImpl.dispatchAsync(DispatcherImpl.java:116)
        at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.dispatchAsync(Request.java:1304)
        at weblogic.jms.dispatcher.Request.dispatchAsync(Request.java:97)
        at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEProducer.doDispatch(FEProducer.java:900)
        at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEProducer.sendRetryDestination(FEProducer.java:1033)
        at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEProducer.send(FEProducer.java:1435)
        at weblogic.jms.frontend.FEProducer.invoke(FEProducer.java:1496)
        at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.Request.wrappedFiniteStateMachine(Request.java:961)
        at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef.invoke(DispatcherServerRef.java:276)
        at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef.handleRequest(DispatcherServerRef.java:141)
        at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef.access$000(DispatcherServerRef.java:34)
        at weblogic.messaging.dispatcher.DispatcherServerRef$2.run(DispatcherServerRef.java:112)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

Ignoring the fact that I've stripped out all the pooling code for raw debugging, I'm using the following configuration with the standard JmsTemplate for sending messages.

```
<beans:bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <beans:property name="environment">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${jms.connectionUrl}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${jms.username}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${jms.password}</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="${jms.connectionFactoryName}" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="destination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="${jms.destinationName}" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <beans:property name="defaultDestination" ref="destination" />

    <beans:property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
    <beans:property name="sessionTransacted" value="false" />
</beans:bean>
```

The equivalent bit of non-Spring code that successfully publishes is below.

```
Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, prop("jms.connectionUrl"));
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, prop("jms.username"));
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, prop("jms.password"));

Context context = new InitialContext(environment);
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(prop("jms.connectionFactoryName"));

Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Destination destination = (Destination) context.lookup(prop("jms.destinationName"));
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
connection.start();

TextMessage tm = session.createTextMessage(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
producer.send(tm);
```

Judging by the exception message, it leads me to believe that the credentials are not being provided at a critical location. The JNDI lookups are successful, and changing any properties (including the credentials) to invalid values causes clear errors to be thrown during initialization, long before attempting to publish.

I initially thought the problem would be solved using `UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter` to ensure the credentials were being provided at creation time, but it resulted in the same error. Additionally, I haven't needed to use this for the simple example above.

Just for completeness, here is revelant the jmsTemplate bit of code.

```
public void sendMessage(final String message) throws JmsException {
    jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
            return textMessage;
        }
    });
}
```

And last but not least, I don't have control or access to the WebLogic instance to where I am publishing. I have a contact who will be reviewing logs to see if there are any important clues, but it could be quite some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered a (non-intuitive) workaround for this issue after some additional research into similar Spring bug reports. I've decided to post this as an answer instead of deleting the question as I hope it will help someone else in the future.

Specifically, I came across [SPR-4720](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-4720) from 2008. John Bakar recommends a fix which appears to do nothing at all, however it does indeed solve the issue above.

Applied to my project, the fix looks like this:

```
public class UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter extends org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter {

    private JndiTemplate jndiTemplate;

    public void setJndiTemplate(JndiTemplate jndiTemplate) {
        this.jndiTemplate = jndiTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    protected Connection doCreateConnection(String username, String password) throws JMSException {
        wlFix();
        return super.doCreateConnection(username, password);
    }

    /**
     * Associate JNDI variables (user and password) with this thread for the
     * benefit of the WL drivers.
     */
    protected void wlFix() {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(jndiTemplate.getEnvironment());
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Weird, right?

All-in-all, for the reference of others, my Spring configuration now looks like this:

```
<beans:bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
    <beans:property name="environment">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${jms.jndiFactory}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${jms.connectionUrl}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${jms.username}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${jms.password}</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="${jms.connectionFactoryName}" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="connectionFactoryAdapter" class="com.company.jms.publisher.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
    <beans:property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
    <beans:property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${jms.username}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${jms.password}" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="cachingConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <beans:property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactoryAdapter" />
    <beans:property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="destinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
    <beans:property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" />
    <beans:property name="destinationResolver" ref="destinationResolver" />
    <beans:property name="defaultDestinationName" value="${jms.publish.destinationName}" />

    <beans:property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
    <beans:property name="sessionTransacted" value="false" />
</beans:bean>
```

I'd be willing to offer a bounty to anyone who is able to authoritatively (no speculation) explain why creating a dummy `InitialContext` and doing nothing with it solves the issue of not properly providing the credentials to WLS.